# Append to Search PHP - Wordpress Filter - WP Job Manager

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I'm trying to write a filter that will append a specific word to all keyword searches, and if there is nothing entered in the search, then it will just include that word alone. This is what I have, but now the search functionality is not registering anything in the search field.

```
add_filter( 'job_manager_indeed_get_jobs_args', 'custom_job_manager_indeed_get_jobs_args' );

function custom_job_manager_indeed_get_jobs_args( $args ) {
    $args['q'] = $search_keywords ? $search_keywords . "designer" : "designer";

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Is this some sort of plugin you are using?  I'm not familiar with what that filter "job_manager_indeed_get_jobs_args" does....

Comment: The plugin is called WP Job Manager - more generally, can you tell me if that is the correct format for appending?

Comment: The problem in your code is that you are not setting $search_keywords it needs to come from the parameter of the function passing the array $args.